# Something to do in or around Colmar in France

Tags: france, children

My wife and I will be travelling to Colmar in Alsace, France, in July with our year-old son. We will be meeting some friends there with their 2 year old son.

What would some suggestions be for things to do that might work for our group? What about if the weather is bad?

We aren't very into wine, and we will have a car.

Comment: Could you please try to make the question more specific? In its current form, it will result in a lot of debate over 'some things' to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like Strasbourg as a place to visit. It's about an hour's drive, or you can take the train if you want an easy trip.

In Strasbourg itself, you've got quite a few [museums](http://www.strasbourg.info/museums/) to visit, but you may need to leave one person outside with the small child... It's worth climbing up the church tower for the view, and there's lots of nice places to see around the old town on foot

Otherwise, in the area you're in there are lots of old castles on hill tops, generally with a really nice walk up through the vineyards and then woods to get to them.